# Flex - Remove horizontallist rollover color

Tags: apache-flex, colors, rollover, horizontallist

I'd like to remove the rollovercolor of a horizontallist (my component has a background image).
I've tried using a css style sheet by setting the "roll-over-color" property to "transparent"... But I get a black background >_<

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks a lot =)

Regards,
BS_C3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style you're looking for  is "useRollOver" and its a bollean, so just set it to false and you should be good to go.

Now if you have a more complicated scenario see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325080/disable-roll-over-color-for-list-or-datagrid-components/2335200#2335200), this was a case where the rollOver was desired for other rollOver events, but wanted it to be transparent.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for your answer. 
Actually, I need the rollover property to be set to true (some events depend on that property). So I think I'll overwrite the horizontallist to remove the highlight color =)

Regards.